# How to cope with the pressure in an exam?

Tags: mental-health, stress, stress-test

I am willing to do *Research* in a particular subject. In order to pursue it I will have to qualify a competitive exam.

I have attempted it 2 times but failed. The reason for the failure is not that I don't study properly but the problem is whenever I see the problems in the exam, I feel as if I would not be able to do it or even if I do it the answers to most of them are wrong.

But the surprising fact is when I come back home and then try them I seem to be doing a different paper. All the problems are easily solved and they seem so easy that I can even see the answers verify that I have done them wrong in the exam.

The same happens during the interview. I fail to answer the easy questions.

The problem is that this phenomenon is repeated several times.

What shall I do? Is any advice available? I could not find a better place than this to ask this question.Is this site suitable for this? Please help.

Comment: Welcome to health SE. I think the question might be suitable for either this site or perhaps Academia SE. I've removed the medication tag, because we cannot recommend any medication, since that would constitute personal medical advice, which is strictly off topic here (there are detailed explanations on meta about this).

Comment: This question is really looking for personal advice which we cannot give.  Maybe a cognitive behavioural therapist will be able to help, maybe not.  It is hard to give any definitive answers to individual problems.